# (temporary) Change in vocal range after straining my voice

Tags: voice

I have noticed that when I strain my voice (intense, hmmm, singing as a part of the public in a rock concert for instance), the next day my vocal range extends greatly in the low range (I'm almost gaining an octave sometimes), at the cost of having a harder time to sing precisely high pitched notes: the voice is shaking, but I can still sing as high pitched as usual. I have a number of questions regarding this:

1. What is the physiological reason behind the change or range ? How are my vocal chords affected ?
2. Is this a bad idea ? My gut feeling is that it doesn't do good to my voice, but I don't really know in fact.
3. What can I do to mitigate that, after the fact ? (I get that avoiding to shout too much in the first place is probably a good idea)
4. Bonus question: is there any way I can get the extension of the vocal range in the low frequencies while keeping my ability to sing in the high frequency range ?

If that has any part to play, I am a tenor.

Comment: Whatever the voice you have is the one you have, and it cannot be physically changed. Get used to the idea to prevent further harm. After that you can learn of mechanics of voice, and figure out _relatively_ harmless ways to change your range, such as breathing glycerol vapor.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph - I doubt what you say is true when my mother reports that she "wrecked her voice" when younger and my range has actually still been gaining low notes (the G# below the C below Middle C has been becoming increasingly convincing this year) and I am scrambling to keep my high notes even though I already turned 30 (I have notably lost the ability to sing the highest note of Christine's part in "The Phantom of the Opera" (song) since I was young, and I keep checking whether I can still hit the C two octaves above Middle C - so far, I still can).

Comment: An edit to refocus into one question might keep this open. Something like "Can I (ab)use straining my voice to safely increase my range?" might work?

Answer (score 4):

1. Straining your voice means you are causing small damage to your vocal cords. This triggers a healing reaction which causes a higher circulation and thus causes some swelling (similar to for example when you have an infection). This then increases the mass of your vocal cords and thus lower the range of your voice.
2. Putting some strain on your voice occasionally will heal well and probably not cause lots of problems. It gets dangerous when you strain your voice too hard or if you do it very frequently, eventually even not leaving enough time to heal. This can eventually lead to damage to your vocal cords that either requires operation or even cannot be completely healed at all. This might drastically reduce your usuable vocal range and your vocal stability! For example straining your voice too much can cause those vocal cords nodules, which are something like callusses for your vocal cords.
3. There are multiple things that cause vocal cord strain. Simply singing high notes will strain your voice. So to some extent you need to be pragmatic with how much you want to use your voice. But such strain can be mitigated a lot by using proper technique. Even in harsh vocals (metal growls &c.) there is a correct way to do it that affects the voice as little as possible and there are "wrong" ways to do it that can cause immense amounts of strain. Similarly shouting can be done with good technique.
4. Technique will allow you to extend you voice in both directions to some extent. But it cannot make your vocal cords longer/shorter or heavier/lighter. So the amount of range you can gain by this will be less and require more work than this magical "suddenly my voice is a fifth lower". Of course there are the old tricks like breathing gas that is lighter than air (making the voice higher) or heavier than air (making the voice lower).
5. Bonus answer: While this swelling does make your voice lower it does not mean you should use this as a means. Because this also means that your vocal cords are slightly hurt and should be strained as little as possible so that they can heal properly. Especially trying to sing particularly high notes is not a very good idea in such a situation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and advice, it makes sense !

Comment: vocal chords = C-E♭-G, D-F♯-A when sung. vocal cords = those things in your neck that vibrate to make noise.

Comment: @shoover You’re right. But then, essentially it is just a different spelling for the same word. Blame the english language for being inconsistent ...

Comment: It may sound the same, but they aren't the same word.  "Cord" has a completely different meaning than "chord."

Comment: @aparente001 "Cord" from french "Corde" from latin "corda", which is an alternative spelling to latin "chorda" from greek "khorde". Originally means a (gut) string. Meanwhile "Chord" from latin "chorda" from greek "khorde". Means as much as a string, just in musical, geometric or anatomical context. So essentially just different spellings of the same word.